# No module named 'pandas.core.arrays.numpy_'

Tags: pandas, numpy

While importing Pandas I encountered the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.arrays.numpy_". The full description is as follows: [error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8jZO.png)

The packages versions are: numpy==1.16.3, pandas = 0.24.2 (Python 3.6.4). I am wondering if it can be due to the incompatibility with numpy newest version.

Comment: Are you using `mypy`?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install --upgrade pandas` ?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, I first upgraded pandas. I believe pandas = 0.24.2  is the newest release. I, however, resolved the issue by downgrading pandas to 0.22.0 and numpy to  1.16.0.

Comment: This could be a pandas bug, please file an issue on github: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/